# Why does List<T>.toArray() return generic Object[] instead of T[]?

Tags: java, generics, collections

For example:

```
List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
String[] aItems = items.toArray(); // type error, because toArray() returns Object[]
```

I understand that this is the way it is, and it cannot be changed. Of course I can cast it to String[], but I wonder what is the idea behind it? Is this a "bug" in Java, or is there a good reason for it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flexibility.

The `toArray()` method without passing any argument returns `Object[]`.

There is a good reason that now you know which type you are expecting and the authors of the method do not know which type of array  to return at runtime due to type erasing. So they just let it be the Super type of all the object which is `Object` and that is why it returns `Object[]`

If you want to specify your type, they are good and return your specific type :)

```
String[] aItems= items.toArray(new String[0]);
```

Comment: Better use `items.toArray(new String[items.size()])` to prevent allocation of additional array object. If array size is equal to `List` size then `items` elements will be copied to the given array and method returns that array, not the newly created array.

Comment: I still don't see why can't List<T>().toArray() return T[] ? I don't see how it would be possible to return anything else.

Comment: Oh I see now. You just can't declare it that way. Well, I don't see it as a good reason. I see it as a language barrier.